# Streaming audio server no audio

Tags: sound, streaming

I'm setting up a streaming audio server using Liquidsoap on Ubuntu server 16.04.1. The issue that I'm having is that the audio will not play unless I log on to the console of the server. I can SSH in but no audio, if I log off of the console the audio stops. I really need this to run unattended from a startup. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running liquidsoap in daemon mode?  ie. with "-d" parameter?

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/liquidsoap.1.html

Comment: That helped on the login issue for sure. I now have a permissions issue on /var/run, if I do a 'sudo chmod 777 /var /run' it now runs sans a login.

Comment: Sorry, the error is:

Comment: sv4491@wtc1stream1:~$ liquidsoap --daemon ./stream.liq
sv4491@wtc1stream1:~$ Fatal error: exception Sys_error("/var/run/liquidsoap: Permission denied")
Raised by primitive operation at file "pervasives.ml", line 272, characters 21-47
Called from file "pervasives.ml", line 275, characters 2-74

Comment: Checkout the liquidsoap quickstart guide: http://liquidsoap.fm/doc-1.2.1/quick_start.html There is a "scripts" section that has suggestions about permissions. The site has a helpful forum for liquidsoap specific issues also.